# Let $L = \{<\}$ prove there is no $L$-theory that has precisely the well ordered sets as models

Tags: logic, model-theory

This is the literal question: let $L$ be the language that only contains the two place relation symbol $<$. Prove  there is no $L$-theory that has precisely the well ordered sets as models.

I assume the $L$-structure must be well ordered with respect to the relation $a^M \leq b^M \iff (a^M <^M b^M) \vee (a^M = b^M)$ where the superscript $M$ denotes it's the interpretation in the $L$-structure $M$.

Here's my work so far:

Suppose such a $L$-theory $T$ does exist. Add the constants $c_1, c_2, ...$ to $L$ giving a new language $L'$. Define the $L'$-theory $T'$ by adding $B := \{c_{n + 1} < c_{n} \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ to $T$.

Now $T'$ cannot be consistent, because then there exists an $L'$-structure $M$ such that $M \models T'$, so $M \models T$, so $M$ is a well ordered set, but also $c_1^M > c_2^M > ...$, which is a contradiction. By the contraposition of the compactness theorem, there must exist a finite subset $A$ of $T'$ that is inconsistent as well. This $A$ must contain a finite number of elements from $B$. I'm stuck here.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Now you want to get a contradiction by showing that $T'$ is consistent. In other words you want to show thst the theory $T_n$, obtained by adding $c_1\gt c_2\gt\cdots\gt c_n$ has a model. Hmm. I gess you can prove something a little stringer, namely, that any theory whose models include arbitrarily large finite ordered sets, also contains a non-well-ordered set.

Comment: A fancier argument: an elementary class which is closed under passage to substructures is (for reasons I forget) axiomatizable by a set of universal sentences, so it is also closed under unions of chains. Since a subset of a well-ordered set is well-ordered, while the union of a chain of well-ordered sets is not necessarily well-ordered, the class of all well-ordered sets can't be elementary.

Comment: @bof Thank you, I think I understand now. Is this correct? For any model $M$ of $T$, we can add the variables $c_i^M$ for those $i$'s that $(c_{i + 1} < c_i)$ is in $T'$ giving $M'$. Then $M' \models c_{i + 1} < c_i$ for those $i$ such that $(c_{i + 1} < c_i)$ is in $T'$. It is impossible that $M'$ is not a well order since it contains only finitely many constants, so also $M' \models T$. So $M \models T'$ and it is consistent, contradiction.

Comment: @PeldePinda "It is impossible that $M'$ is not a well order since it contains only finitely many constants." No, the number of constants interpreted in $M'$ has nothing to do with whether it's a well-order. $M'$ might have infinitely many elements that aren't the interpretations of any of the $c_i$. The reason $M'$ is a well order is that $M'\models T$, and every model of $T$ is a well order by hypothesis.

Comment: Just take the natural numbers, with the finitely many constants in $A$ assigned appropriately, as your model of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it would be better to give an answer rather than carry on with the comments. Your argument contains the key ideas but doesn't quite fit together. To fix it, argue like this:

Let $T$ be any $L$-theory that has every well-founded set as a model. As you suggest, we can extend $L'$ by adding constants $c_n$ and consider the set of sentences $B = \{ c_n > c_{n+1} \mid n \in \Bbb{N} \}$. Then any finite subset of $T \cup B$ is consistent, since it has a model in the well-founded ordered set $\Bbb{N}$. By the compactness theorem, $T \cup B$ has a model. $M$ say. Since every sentence in $B$ holds in $M$, the $c_n$ form an infinite descending chain in $M$, so $M$ is not well-ordered. Thus any $L$-theory that has every well-founded set as a model also has models that are not well-founded. Hence there is no $L$-theory whose models are precisely the well-founded sets.